# Get "memberOf" in LDAP3 search for a specific user

Tags: ldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I have an example result from LDAP like this:

```
USERID123, Users, UserProvisioning, Production, ztb.icb.company.com
dn: CN=USERID123, ,OU=Users,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: USERID123
sn: Mueller
c: DE
l: Frankfurt
title: M.Sc.
telephoneNumber: +49 69 136 27289
givenName: Lukas
distinguishedName: CN=USERID123,OU=Users,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=zt
b,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20191023230941.0Z
whenChanged: 20200907052944.0Z
displayName: Mueller, Lukas
uSNCreated: 21302914
memberOf: CN=GG_APP-013979-DQI-KYC-PROD-CONSUMER-GCRR,OU=Groups,OU=UserProvisi
oning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com
memberOf: CN=GG_APP-013479-DQI-KYC-DEV-CONSUMER-GCRR,OU=Groups,OU=UserProvisi
oning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com
memberOf: CN=GG_APP-011479-DQI-KYC-TUD-CONSUMER-GCRR,OU=Groups,OU=UserProvisi
oning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com
```

I am trying to get all "memberOf" for the User "USERID123" in Python LDAP3.

I tried the following:

```
if conn.bind():
    conn.search(
        search_base='OU=Groups,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com',
        search_filter='(objectClass=group)',
        search_scope='SUBTREE',
        attributes=['memberOf']
    )

    for entry in conn.entries:
        print(entry.memberOf.values)
```

But I am not able to recreate the query in conn.search to find the "memberOf" for a specific user. How can I do this query to get my desired results in a ldap3 query?

Comment: You can see all the values of memberOf in the " example result from LDAP".

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the values of memberOf in the "example result from LDAP".

If you are really asking for all the groups the user is a [Member](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Groups) of then your search would be more like:

```
conn.search( search_base='OU=Groups,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com',
search_filter='&((objectClass=group)(member=CN=USERID123,OU=Users,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com))',
search_scope='SUBTREE',
attributes=['member']
```

Or if using Microsoft Active Directory use this filter:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=USERID123,OU=Users,OU=UserProvisioning,OU=Production,DC=ztb,DC=icb,DC=company,DC=com))
```